# How to run start up scripts on Amazon linux?

Tags: linux, init-script, amazon-ec2, aws

I'm trying to create some script that should run on start.

Now I've created some myScript file under the /etc/init.d/
and then run  `sudo chkconfig --add myScript;`

`chkconfig --list myScript` output is:
myScript             0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off

**myScript:**

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 2345 98 02
# description:
# processname:

# Source function library.
if [ -f /etc/init.d/functions ] ; then
  . /etc/init.d/functions
elif [ -f /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ] ; then
  . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
else
  exit 0
fi
KIND="_"

start() {
   echo starting `date` >> ~/myScript.log
}

stop() {
   echo stopping myScript
}

restart() {
   echo restarting
}

case "$1" in
  start)
          start
        ;;
  stop)
          stop
        ;;
  restart)
          restart
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
esac
exit $?
```

Now I can successfully run `service myScript start` and log record will be appended.
But if I run `sudo reboot` or restart the instance with AWS UI console it doesn't work as was expected.

Although `runlevel` output is:
N 3

Need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `chkconfig` configuration will work if you `shutdown` your instance.

I had created a test script on my machine and it works if I shutdown the instance and doesn't work when I restart it.